# Files and folders everywhere

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

I hate to see these perfect examples of our tag problem go, but, oh well.

[Please help clean up the tags](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file+or+folder):

- [file](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file) <s>1407</s> - <s>679</s> 141 questions
- [folder](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/folder) <s>1129</s> - <s>857</s> 319 questions

Comment: Moving them over to `filesystems` maybe?

Comment: @DanielBeck Maybe *very* selectively. From what I've seen over the past weeks, while cleaning up tags, people like to use these two whenever a file or a folder is involved in their problem. `filesystems` is actually used almost as badly.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg What about if a user has a specific question concerning a *file*, but not a *folder*? For example, maybe they are attempting to delete the contents of a *folder*, but they are only able to delete the *folders* inside.

Comment: @zyboxenterprises They should tag their question with the tag for the operating system they're working with and possibly the tool they're using to attempt the deletion. Using any other additional tag is not helping anyone. Especially if it's `delete`, `file` or `folder`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Very true. Using generic tags such as `delete`, `file`, or `folder` will just confuse everyone, and will probably get that question closed to boot.

Comment: Is there some post where concensus was reached on the 'folder' tag?  Folders can be very different from files, and that tag can help differentiate between the two use cases.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Files and folders are different... Thanks for your insights.

Comment: @LanceRoberts IMO, folders (actually directory) in most files systems are just inodes or journals. The concept of directory is most, if not all, of the times dependent of the filesystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All file and folder related garbage has been removed.